# Как корректно обновить страницу после обновления div?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, html

Делаю, чтобы содержимое  обновлялось при нажатии на ссылку.

**Script**

```
    <script src = "history.js/scripts/bundled/html4+html5/jquery.history.js"> </script>
    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
     $(function(){

    $('.sidebar a').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var linkLocation = $(this).attr('href');
        History.pushState(null, document.title, linkLocation);
        loadPage(linkLocation);


    return false;
    });

    function loadPage(url) {            
        $('.content').load(url);
    }

});
</script>
```

**Html**

```
...
<body>

<div class="container">
  <div class="sidebar">
    <ul class="nav">
      <li><a href="page1.html" > № 1</a></li>
      <li><a href="page2.html" > № 2</a></li>
      <li><a href="page3.html" > № 3</a></li>
      <li><a href="page4.html" > № 4</a></li>
      <li><a href="page5.html" > № 5</a></li>
      <li><a href="page6.html" > № 6</a></li>
    </ul>
...
</div></div></body>
```

**Page1.html**

```
    ...
    <body>
    <h1>№ 1</h1>
    <p>Вася Пупкин</p>
    <br>
    <form action =select.php method=get>    
            <div align=center>Пиши сюда<input type=text name=param1> <br><br>
                <table border=0 width=80%>
                    <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <td align=center> <input type=reset   value= Очистить > </td>
                            <td align=center>  <input type=submit name=send value= Отправить>   </td> 
                            <td align=center> <input type="button" onClick="history.back();" value="Назад"/> </td>
                        </tr>  
                    </tbody>   
                </table>     
      </div>  
    </form> 

</body>
```

При нажатии на ссылку, содержимое div меняется, а в адресной строке меняется URL(допустим на `mysite.ru/page1.html`), но если обновить страницу, браузер, ясное дело, обращается непосредственно к самому файлу `page1.html`. Я искал решение в Интернете, кажется. в этой ситуации нужно использовать хэш, но я все равно не понимаю, каким образом это должно работать. Прошу помощи.

Comment: Это надо реализовать серверной части... А не клиентской...

Comment: @Air, да это курсач, тут можно)

Comment: а сам jQuery подключен ?

Comment: @Максим-Ленский, да, подключен.

Comment: Ты можешь URL "страницы" положить за решетку, то есть вместо `mysite.ru/page1.html` сделать `mysite.ru#page1.html`. В этом случае браузер будет подгружать ту же страницу из корня, а потом искать якорь с именем `page1.html`, и если найдет видимый якорь с таким ID, то промотает к нему. Дальше при загрузке страницы тебе просто надо будет через JS определить текущую страницу и показать именно ее

Answer (score 0):

У тебя jQuery НЕ подключен..  вот эта ссылка никуда не ведёт...

```
history.js/scripts/bundled/html4+html5/jquery.history.js
```

Вместо:

```
  <script src = "history.js/scripts/bundled/html4+html5/jquery.history.js"> </script>
```

Пропиши:

```
  <script src = "https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"> </script>
```

***P.S*** То что ты пытаешься сделать без **хотя бы локального** сервера не получиться.

Comment: у меня все было подключено, просто я не скопировал эту строку. А файл history.js лежит в папке. С подключением проблем нет, скрипт работает

Comment: Хорошо, но тогда другая проблема, это надо делать локально, так как он ругается на отсутствие `http` протокола.

Comment: @Ziclear, да, это все крутится на localhost (denwer)

Comment: И даже с localhost не работает? В чем конкретно проблема? При обновлении страницы тебе надо что бы браузер шёл на "домашнюю" страницу?